# how to update mongodb using button in html, pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, nosql, pymongo

I have a `base.html` that has items, and button for user to click.

```
                                <p class="card-text">{{data[0].name}}</p>
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <form action="/update/<%= data[0]._id %>" method="PATCH">
                                    <p style="margin-right:5px;">Available: {{data[0].inventory}}</p>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Add to cart</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

And I have `hello.py` python file that runs the server.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
app = Flask(__name__)
 

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def mongoTest():
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client.ecommerce
    collection = db.items
    results = collection.find()
    # client.close()
    return render_template('base.html', data=results)


@app.route("/update/:id", methods=["PATCH"])
def update_inventory(id):    
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client.ecommerce
    id=request.values.get("_id")    
    db.items.update_one({ '_id': id}, {'$inc': {'inventory': -1}}, upsert=False)
    results2 = db.items.find()
    return render_template('base.html', data=results2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, it does not update the inventory values.
How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the id a string? if so it needs to be transformed into an ObjectId. (in most cases, you let mongo handle ids, so ids are ObjectId, not strings).

```py
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

@app.route("/update/:id", methods=["PATCH"])
def update_inventory(id):    
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
    db = client.ecommerce
    id = ObjectId(request.values.get("_id"))
    db.items.update_one({ '_id': id}, {'$inc': {'inventory': -1}}, upsert=False)
    results2 = db.items.find()
    return render_template('base.html', data=results2)
```

Otherwise, you have to check:

- if the id exists, if not return an error?
- "items" collection doest exist? (not Item nor item?)

Comment: ohh ids are ObjectId! then how do I handle it..? and "items" collection exists

Comment: Just see the answer: you have to pass the string into ObjectId:

Comment: is this html part correct ? getting the id?<form action="/update/<%= data[0]._id %>" method="PATCH">

Comment: and having @app.route("/update/:id", methods=["PATCH"])

Comment: :id is actually getting the id